# implementing a callback in TimelineJS

Tags: javascript

In [TimelineJS](https://github.com/VeriteCo/TimelineJS) I want to implement a callback that would be fired every time the slide (the main panel in the center) changes whether that change happens by clicking on the "right" or "left" buttons on the sides, or by clicking on an event in the timeline  in the bottom time panel. I could not find any information on such a callback other than a reference to it in [Issue 82](https://github.com/VeriteCo/TimelineJS/issues/82) from a year ago.

Suggestions on how to start with this? (In other words, I have no idea even where to begin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timeline JS fires an event whenever it is updated, the code is at line 5274 of the latest version:

```
function upDate() {
    config.current_slide = current_slide;
    VMM.fireEvent(layout, "UPDATE");
};
```

The code for fireEvent is:

```
VMM.fireEvent = function(element, the_event_type, the_data) {
    var e;
    var _event_type = "click";
    var _data = [];

    if (the_event_type != null && the_event_type != "") {
        _event_type = the_event_type;
    }
    if (the_data != null && the_data != "") {
        _data = the_data;
    }

    if( typeof( jQuery ) != 'undefined' ){
        jQuery(element).trigger(_event_type, _data);

        //return e;
    }

};
```

Then important part there is:

```
jQuery(element).trigger(_event_type, _data);
```

So, all you need to do is figure out what element layout is, so I would temporatily edit the upDate function to:

```
function upDate() {
    console.log($(layout).attr('id') + ' : ' + $(layout).attr('class'));
    config.current_slide = current_slide;
    VMM.fireEvent(layout, "UPDATE");
};
```

And see what it logs for the class / id of the element.  Then, say it comes back with the class being 'timeline', for example, you would write something like this:

```
$('.timeline').on("UPDATE", function() {
    your_function_that_does_whatever_you_need();
});
```

Comment: Per the instructions on TimelineJS, I am using `storyjs-embed.js` and calling `createStoryJS`. If I use `timeline.js` I am not clear how to fire the timeline. Also, in my latest version of `timeline.js` the `function upDate()` actually occurs two times on lines 5275 and 7758. And finally, I am not sure which element you are referring to when you write that all I "need to do is figure out what element layout is."

Comment: the function upDate has this line:
`VMM.fireEvent(layout, "UPDATE");`

The layout variable is the first argument, which is used in fireEvent:
`fireEvent = function(element, the_event_type, the_data)`

So, inside that function, element == layout.  It then calls
`jQuery(element).trigger(_event_type, _data);`

So, if you know what the variable element is (which is actually the same as the variable layout in the first function), you can use jQuery to attach a function to that event on that element.  You basically do `$(element).on(event, function() { ... });`

Comment: Thanks. So, I figured out that when I click on the right/left arrows, the element class is "vco-slider" and when I click on the event in the timeline, the class is "vco-navigation." However, `$('.vco-navigation').on("UPDATE", function() {console.log("hello from navigation");});` does nothing. Otoh, if I add the function directly to `timeline.js` inside `VMM.fireEvent()` it does work. Of course, I'd rather keep my mods outside `timeline.js`. Also, I need to know info about the slide that is loaded. I dumped `console.log(_data);` but got an empty array `[]`. Suggestions?

Comment: My guess is `$('.vco-navigation').on("UPDATE", function() {console.log("hello from navigation");});` does nothing because when it is defined in my script, that element with class `.vco-navigation` hasn't yet been created. So, that callback function needs to be defined *after* the timeline has been loaded. The event type is "DATAREADY" that I need to listen for, however, since there is no callback system exposed, how do I do that?

Comment: You'll have to play around, you may be able to delegate the event:  $('body').on("UPDATE", '.vco-navigation', function() { ... });

You may simply need to hack it with a timeout: setTimeout(function() {  $('.vco-navigation').on("UPDATE", function() { ... }), 500);

Or you may need to directly modify the script, the simplest way may just be to trigger your own events when you need to, you can add $('body').trigger('your_event') wherever you need to.  

That's about all the help I can offer.

Comment: Thanks much for your patience. `$("body").on("UPDATE", ".vco-slider", function() { .. });` did the job. Now I have another question, but that will, well, another question. Thanks again.

Comment: @dave I've tried using the 'update', 'loaded' and 'message' events.   I can listen to them all, but they are occurring before the actual event is complete and hence aren't accurately reporting on when a slide has been updated.